# I can't insert data in to database by form using CakePHP2.4

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am new to CakePHP and just created my stuff.

I can't add data into database from form using CakePHP2,4.My controller page is StaffsController.php.View page is in view->Staff->add.ctp,My model page is Staff.php.table name - staffs id int pk title var char(200).

```
//My Code.


class StaffsController extends AppController 
{

    function index()
    {
    $this->set('posts', $this->Staff->find('all')); 
    }
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Staff->create();
            $post_data = $this->request->data;
            if ($this->Staff->save($post_data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('New post saved successfully to the database'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to save the post to the database.'));
        }
}

}


// add.ctp

 <h1>Add Post</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Post');
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->end('Save');
?>

//My Model Page 

<? php
class Staff extends AppModel
 {

 }
?>
```

Comment: Would you mind deleting your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421225/i-cant-data-in-to-database-by-form-using-cakephp2-4)

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Staff');
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->end('Save');

dont use create('post');
```